# Need number range in regular expression

Tags: regex, expression, yacc, lex

I have question about regular expression. I need code with range from -1000 to 1000.

I know from 0 to 1000

```
([0-9]{1,3}|1000)
```

But i can not figure it with -1000  -  1000

I appreciate some help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why do you want regular expressions for this?

Comment: @WouterJ Thanks for the answer. I'm working on calculator with yacc and lex, and I have to define allowed numbers, because of that, I need from minus thousand up to thousand (working project with restrictions). But is that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
(-?1000|-?\d{1,3})
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but i test it on regexr web site and, is that better with ^(at the beggining) and $(in the end) ?

Comment: Well, I think it depends on what you want.

Comment: I put this in my lex file, and it doesn't work well , I don't know why :/
FIXED, i put [0-9] instead of \d , Thanks a lot!